# Linux bluetooth audio issues. No working mic/sound via HSP

Tags: linux, audio, debian, bluetooth

Running crunchbang++ ( debian 9 ).  MPOW-059 bluetooth headphones.

Bluetooth device:  Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0

If I connect them via a2dp sink I can listen to music. Pandora/vlc whatever.

If I switch to HSP/HFP to be able to use the microphone I get no audio and no working mic.

I have the built in soundcard and hdmi disabled.

The end goal is being able to listen to media, then when a call comes in I can pause that and answer the call, then back to music.

I've tried sound preferences, and pavucontrol, both with the same result.